# Why only fully connected diagrams contribute to $T$-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

In Peskin & Schroeder's introduction to QFT, he wrote:

> only fully connected diagrams, in which all external lines are connected to each other, contribute to the $T$ matrix.

I don't understand this statement.

Suppose we have many particles in initial and final state, and two independent reactions take place, then we will have a diagram which contains two pieces. The initial and final state are different, so the diagram cannot be classified in the `1` in $S$-matrix. So it should be in $T$-matrix. Do I have anything wrong?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82387/2451 and links therein.